# Lower field for all records in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb

Basically I have the accounts setup like this:

```
{
 'email': 'Matt@GMAIL.com',
 'others': '...'
}
```

In sql, I was used to just searching where LOWER(email) = LOWER(search), however I found that can't easily (and quickly) be done in mongo.

So I'm trying to do something like:

`UPDATE accounts SET email = LOWER(email);`

or:

```
accounts.update_many({}, {
            '$set': {
                'email': lower(email)
            }
        }, upsert=False)
```

Any idea how to do this in Mongo?

PS: I'm using PyMongo driver

Comment: As far as I know, you can not yet do this in PyMongo (process functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missunderstood your question..
i can only purpose a python function :)

```
def accounts_to_lower():
    for account in accounts.find({'email': {'$exists': True}):
        accounts.update_one({'email': account.get('email'}, {
            '$set': {
                'email': account.get('email'}.lower()
            }
        }, upsert=False)
```

Comment: Yeah... I was afraid of that... Okay, I'll mark it as solved, since I don't think there is an 'easy' answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a cleaner code for you. :)

```
def add_user_to_table(table, username, **kwargs):
    """ Add user to given table, with given arguments.
    """
    data = { 'name' : username }
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        data[key] = value
    table.insert(data)

def update_query_in_table(table, query, action='$set',
        multi=False, **kwargs):
    """ Updates user information using **kwargs.
        Either updates using action='$set' or deletes using action='$unset'
    """
    update = {action : {}}
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        update[action][key] = value

    upd = table.update(query, update, multi=multi)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Initializing Database
    """
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    database = client.connectSysDatabase
    userTable = database.users

    # Deletes everything at every run, this is a test program, it won't
    # affects us much here to delete and re-add for the example purpose.
    userTable.delete_many({})

    # Creating our Database
    add_user_to_table(userTable, 'John', grade='member')
    add_user_to_table(userTable, 'Kilian', grade='member')
    add_user_to_table(userTable, 'Raphael', grade='member')

    # Querying all the 'member' in 'grade'.
    query = { 'grade' : 'member' }

    # Will update only one grade to 'Captain'.
    update_query_in_table(userTable, query, multi=False, grade="Captain")

    # Will update all grade to 'Captain'.
    update_query_in_table(userTable, query, multi=True, grade="Captain")
```

---

To answer the comment just below... "Given your example, with the username == "John", how can I convert his username, and everyone elses to lowercase?"

You need to make a query, with something all the user you want have in common (this is basic programming for now). You can make a query like `{'username': {'$exists': True}`, or `{ 'grade' : 'member' }`. Here, it would return **every user**, or **every user which are *member*** (since this is a collection with only users in it).

Then, using `**kwargs`, you update with the value you wish to update. It is true that the question, as it is right now, hasn't been answered as you would need to add an arg `func` to the `update_query_in_table` to make it work like a charm as following :

```
def update_query_in_table(table, query, action='$set',
        multi=False, func=lambda x: x, **kwargs):
    """ Updates user information using **kwargs.
        Either updates using action='$set' or deletes using action='$unset'
    """
    update = {action : {}}
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        # By default, func does nothing.
        update[action][key] = func(value)

    upd = table.update(query, update, multi=multi)
```

By default, func does nothing, but you can make it do something using `update (...), func = lambda x: x.lower())`. But we are just decorating a function to make the update **cleaner** and **easier** (which is pythonic, *IMHO*). The thing I wanted you to notice is the **multi** option, that is what you are seeking.

Originally, you wanted to do :

```
# Considering update_many() works, as I always use "update". :)
accounts.update_many({}, {
            '$set': {
                'email': lower(email)
            }
        }, upsert=False)
```

You could just have done :

```
# Considering update_many() works, as I always use "update". :)
accounts.update_many({}, {
            '$set': {
                'email': lower(email)
            }
        }, upsert=False, multi=True)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's good code and all, but doesn't answer the question.

Given your example, with the username == "John", how can I convert his username, and everyone elses to lowercase?

Your code has the same flaw mine did.  I left caps in there, and if someone tried to log in as, "john", it would fail.

Comment: I made a clean update of my post for you, I hope it gives you more insight about your original problem. It might be a bit long, but I invite you to read it and give me your opinion. :)