# add documents to collection pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5a66f98facb83b71b36aa44a'), 'UID': '', 'profile': {'firstName': '', 'lastName': '', 'email': ''},  'status': 'ACT'}
```

but now I want to add to this collection a list of other documents (in python I have a list of dicts -> *datilist*) in order to:

- update existing fields values if the index field matches with the one already present and eventually add new missing keys/value pairs
- add to the collection if there is no match against index field value

I have created an index with this statement

```
db.utenti.createIndex( { "profile.email": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

In order to avoid duplicates.

I've tried to perform something like this:

```
utenti.update_many({},datilist.$[],upsert=True)
```

But obviously there is something that I am missing.. I think that this should be a one liner for Mongodb, I'm a newbie.

Comment: You want to add a `datilist` key, with `[]` as value ? It is unclear to me, could you post some little code ?

Comment: @IMCoins I've updated the question with further details.. datilist is not a key but it's my list of dictionaries.

Comment: Have you read [how to update in pymongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and [how to format the update parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter) ? If that helps you, you can [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291139/lower-field-for-all-records-in-mongo/48291663#48291663) I gave somewhere else. This is not the same topic, but you could still see how to update properly. It's still unclear to me what you are trying to do.